# How did `sxhash` in Common Lisp get its name?

Tags: common-lisp, terminology, language-history

Or, what does the “*sx*” stand for?

---

See what I mentioned here: [SXHASH](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sxhash.htm#sxhash)

Comment: What the accepted answer said is reasonable (*sx* stands for *s-expr/struct*), I will also post an answer in my spare time as a supplement. For now, you can see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Hash.html#index-sxhash_002dequal) and notice that the “*equal*” in the function name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [**[PDF]** LISP: Program is Data - A Historical Perspective on MACLISP](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/White-Program_Is_Data-1977-From_MACSYMA77.pdf)
 published in [Proceedings of the 1977 MACSYMA Users' Conference](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AztDAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=SXHASH&source=bl&ots=n6ZcJv53qD&sig=ACfU3U3pO7co4IpJmUhzXTq-x80e09ZJtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiajausnMP9AhVFaqQEHfmSBi44KBDoAXoECCEQAw#v=onepage&q=SXHASH&f=false):

> In 1973, White coded an s-expression hashing algorithm called SXHASH, which has been useful to
> routines doing canonicalization of list structure [...]

White here refers to Jon L White I guess.

"SX" is a common abbreviation for "S-Expression" (Structured Expression) frequently used in the [Incompatible Timesharing System](https://github.com/PDP-10/its) source code.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, two minutes after I posted the question, one person gave a longer answer (though it has since been deleted). It was a weird answer, and I think he/she probably used AI to answer my question and it was wrong (conflict with your answer). It has a bad effect on the community. What can I do to help the community the next time I encounter this situation?

Comment: You can flag the answer depending on your reputation you can vote to delete it etc.